# Is it safe to reuse static property CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Unit)

Tags: java, kotlin, completable-future

Should I define CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Unit) in some static class and reuse it in all code to not call CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Unit) again, or will it not be the same CompletableFuture after each future.thenSomething call? (I don't want to have static property with infinitely growing callback queue after each use)

I've found that CompletableFuture only has two variables which are not static or final, but I am not sure if I will be able to find answer faster than community, and also I didn't find similar question, hence posted this one for future readers

```
volatile Object result;
volatile CompletableFuture.Completion stack;
```

Comment: `Unit` is not defined.

Comment: There is no point in reusing a lightweight object like this always-completed future. It's not clear why you need such a future so often that you even think about it.

Comment: @Holger, I need a fair async read write lock which doesn't spin or blocks thread, but passes task to Executor (in my case VertxEventLoopExecutor, which should reschedule task) to not block event loop. I noticed that I construct and return completed future on multiple occasions, not only in this class

Comment: "a fair async read write lock which doesn't spin or blocks thread" contains multiple self-contradictions. Apparently, the only thing you're actually doing, is submitting task to the executor. The completed future doesn't add anything to the process.

Comment: @Holger, I have AtomicBoolean isLocked, I CAS it, if I can not get lock, I submit task to executor. It delays single task, but it allows EventLoopExecutor to execute more tasks, while lock can not be obtained, effectively serving more tasks without switching context. With not-scheduling executor, like if we have Guava-like DirectExecutor, it just spins. I don't believe I should protect this idea and this - 'There is no point in reusing a lightweight object like this always-completed future' is not always true

Comment: And withing this entire lengthy description, there is not a single mentioning of what the `CompletableFuture` should do, q.e.d. Further, this logic clearly can't guaranty fairness and doesn't contain a read write lock logic.

Comment: @Holger, I can describe you the logic and send you tests, which pass (RRR, RRW ... WWW), but I don't believe understanding my reasons will help you to answer a question, which should probably sound like 'Is it safe to reuse static completedFuture'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209932/discussion-between-ivan-ivanyuk-and-holger).

Comment: A single `AtomicBoolean` has only two states, hence, can't be a read/write lock, point. Narrowing the question to "Is it safe to reuse an already completed CompletedFuture", the answer is, as long as the code is well-behaving, not using the `obtrude...` methods, it is fine. You may also create a subclass overriding the `obtrude...` methods to make it really safe. But it's still not worth the effort, to potentially save the creation of a temporary object holding only two fields.

Comment: @Holger, it can't and it isn't, I use <br/>private val asyncAtomicCaller = AsyncAtomicCaller<Unit>()
    private val lockTypeEnumList = LinkedList<LockTypeEnum>()
    private val readLockCountList = LinkedList<Int>()
    private val waitingLockAcquireFutureList = LinkedList<CompletableFuture<Unit>>()<br/> but I don't think it should be part of a question, which you answered as could, thank you very much. I will dig more myself and read other answers later